# Is there a more pythonic way to evaluate "for some"?

Tags: python, syntactic-sugar, control-structure

Consider the pseudocode

```
if P(S) for some S in Iterator:
    Do something
```

When I write this in python I usually end up writing something like

```
for S in Iterator:
    if P(S):
        Do something
        break
```

Or if I want to avoid nesting an if in a loop

```
i = 0
while i < len(S) and not P(S[i]):
    i+=1
if i < len(S):
    Do something
```

Both of these are *irritating* to use. The code is direct yet my intent in pseudocode feels somewhat obfuscated. I might instead try to write

```
if [P(S) for S in Iterator if P(s)]:
    Do something
```

but that list comprehension will enumerate the entire iterator (I believe) and the P(S) is mentioned twice, and overloading the if statement with the list feels ugly.

Is there a better/more pythonic way to write that pseudocode in python?

Comment: At least regarding your "P(S) is mentioned twice" issue, you don't care *what* is in the list, only if it is empty or not. `[S for S in Iterator if P(S)]` would suffice.